# How do I change the display name of a custom ConfigurationSection?

Tags: .net

I'm building a custom ConfigurationSection for use in a demo application. The name I gave the class inheriting from ConfigurationSection is the section name the application looks for in the config file. How do I change this behavior?

Here's the skeleton of the class inheriting from `ConfigurationSection`:

```
public class LongNameBecauseItsTheResultOfFollowingAnOtherwiseGoodConvention: ConfigurationSection
{
   ...    
}
```

And in the `app.config` file it wants to see the following section:

```
<LongNameBecauseItsTheResultOfFollowingAnOtherwiseGoodConvention>
  ...
</LongNameBecauseItsTheResultOfFollowingAnOtherwiseGoodConvention>
```

How can I use a shorter section name in the `app.config` yet follow our convention in the source code?

Comment: Personally, I would just make an exception or amend the convention for long names. It's potentially more confusing to have a config section name that doesn't match between the code and the config file. But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

When defining the `ConfigurationSection` in the `<configSections>` element of the `app.config` file, you can assign a different name.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="ABC123" type="namespaceName.className, assemblyName"/>
  </configSections>
</configuration>
```